# Difficulty generating Wavesurfer on my live website. Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated

Tags: javascript, html, wavesurfer.js

I require help with wavesurfer.js. It functions correctly on my localhost, but after uploading it to Hostinger, the wavesurfer is not being generated. Any guidance would be appreciated.

I have uploaded it to https://subdomain.example.com

```js
const playBtn = document.getElementById('playBtn');




const wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: '#waveform',
    waveColor: '#ddd',
    progressColor: '#ff006c',
    barWidth: 4,
    responsive: true,
    height: 90,
    barRadius: 4,
  });
  
  wavesurfer.load('./assets/media/koolFM.wav');

  playBtn.onclick = function(){

    wavesurfer.playPause();
    if(playBtn.src.includes("play.png")){

        playBtn.src = "./assets/media/pause.png";

    } else {

        playBtn.src = "./assets/media/play.png";

    }

  }
  

  wavesurfer.on('finish', function(){

    playBtn.src = "./assets/media/play.png";
    wavesurfer.stop();


  })
```

```html
    <div class="hero-audio">
        <div class="music">
            <h1 class="text-center">H1 tag here</h1>
            <p class="text-center">Paragraph here</p>
            <div class="track">
                <img src="./assets/media/play.png" id="playBtn" alt="">
                <div id="waveform"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Please refer to the images below:

[Image 1: The condition in my local host.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSm2q.png)

[Image 2: In the live hosting, wavesurfer is not generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpged.png)

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: I got this in console:

GET https://subdomain.example.com/assets/media/koolFM.wav 404 (Not Found)